# Need to sense a keystroke in VBscript to end a loop

Tags: vbscript

I am really new to VBscript; like I litteraly just started about a half hour ago, but I just need it for a super simple program. It runs a Do Until loop, and I want it to stop when I press the spacebar. I have everything else done, I just need to know if/how to detect the keystroke. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your script into an hta file (basically a web page with a program's permissions) see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536473(VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536473%28VS.85%29.aspx). Then set up an event handler for space key. Instead of a do loop do a timer and do 1 thing a timer tick. Your space key event handler cancels the timer.

**onkeydown Event**

---

Fires when the user presses a key.

Syntax

Inline HTML `<ELEMENT onkeydown = "handler" ... >`  All platforms 
Event property `object.onkeydown = handler` JScript only 
`object.onkeydown = GetRef("handler")` Visual Basic Scripting Edition (VBScript) 5.0 or later only 
`Named script <SCRIPT FOR = object EVENT = onkeydown>`  Internet Explorer only

Event Information

Bubbles Yes 
Cancels Yes 
To invoke Press any keyboard key.
Default action Returns a number specifying the keyCode of the key that was pressed.

**setInterval Method**

---

Evaluates an expression each time a specified number of milliseconds has elapsed.

Syntax

```
iTimerID = window.setInterval(vCode, iMilliSeconds [, sLanguage])
```

Parameters

vCode Required. Variant that specifies a function pointer or string that indicates the code to be executed when the specified interval has elapsed. 
iMilliSeconds Required. Integer that specifies the number of milliseconds. 
sLanguage Optional. String that specifies any one of the possible values for the LANGUAGE attribute.

Return Value

Integer. Returns an identifier that cancels the timer with the clearInterval method.

Remarks

The setInterval method continuously evaluates the specified expression until the timer is removed with the clearInterval method.

Answer (score 1):

This is a operative, non advisable (you are advised), option. But it generates a line write to console (jump to next line) every time it checks for the key press.

```
Function GetParentProcessId()
    Dim processesList, process
    Set processesList = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
    Set processesList = processesList.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE (Name = 'cscript.exe') AND Commandline LIKE '%"+WScript.ScriptName+"%'" )
    For Each process in processesList
        GetParentProcessId = process.ParentProcessId
    Next 
End Function 

Dim parentProcessId
    parentProcessId = GetParentProcessId()

Dim shell
    Set shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Dim input, i

    i=0
    Do While True
        WScript.StdOut.Write "Press space to stop process. Step [" & i & "]" & vbCR
        i = i + 1
        If (i Mod 10) = 0 Then 
            shell.AppActivate parentProcessId
            shell.SendKeys "~"
            input = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine()
            If input = " " Then
                Exit Do
            End If
        End If
        WScript.Sleep 50
    Loop

    WScript.StdOut.WriteLine vbCFLF & "Process ended"
    WScript.Quit
```